# Modifying a struct member via a pointer in a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, member

I have tried to go for pseudo code to try to focus on the problem and remove anything extraneous. I have a definition of a struct in a header file:

**struct.h**

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
} structname;

static structname struct_array[NUMBER];
```

**start.c**

```
#include "struct.h"

static void functionA() {
    function1 (&struct_array[index]);
}
```

**Setup.c**

```
#include "struct.h"

int function1(structname * name) {
    int result = 0;   
    name->value = 2;   
    printf("The value before function2: d", result->value);   
    result = function2(name);   
    printf("The resulting value: d", result->value);
    printf("The address of the member to be modified is: %p", &(name->value));   
    return result;
}
```

**Modification.c**

```
#include "struct.h"

int function2(structname * name) {
    int result = 0;
    name->value = 1;
    printf("The resulting value: d", name->value);
    printf("The address of the member to be modified is: %p", &(name->value));
    return result;
}
```

---

**This returns:**

```
The value before function2: 2
The resulting value: 1
The address of the member to be modified is: 12345
The resulting value:  2
The address of the member to be modified is: 12345
```

Here's the thing: the addresses are the same. How can the functions appear to be modifying a member of a struct but upon return of the function, the struct member retains its original value?

Should I be using the `extern` keyword? How and where?

Edit:
I thought I would do some tests to see if I could perhaps find the issue. All I have done is to confuse myself. So it turns out, if I add a second member to the struct, say int nextValue, the modification works on that and returns, and I can test it, and it is modified. So how can it work on one member and not another?! I'm flummoxed. Any ideas of perhaps what to test?

Comment: `static structname struct_array[NUMBER];` Are you aware that every C file (translation unit) which includes `struct.h` has its own copy of `struct_array`? How does it change if you replace `static` by `extern`?

Comment: This code you've provided cannot **compile**, `int result = 0;` followed by `  printf("The value before function2: d", result->value);` is invalid. Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: Just a guess since you did not provide your code... You put this in the header file: `static structname struct_array[NUMBER];`. Each translation unit gets its own copy of the array. You might consider putting the array in a single C file, and then declaring the array as `extern` in a header so the object files in the program uses the one array.

Answer (score 2):

You got the definition of your global array wrong. The way you have written it you have two global arrays (with the same name) that's why the function doesn't appear to change anything.

Do it like this

```
struct.h
typedef struct {
   int value;
} structname

extern structname struct_array[];

Setup.c
#include "struct.h"

structname struct_array[NUMBER];
```

That's how globals work, you *define* them in one .c file (doesn't have to be Setup.c, just pick any one), and you *declare* them with `extern` in a header file.

Comment: Though, I'm still not sure about the printed equal addresses...

Comment: @Scheff The code in the question doesn't even compile, and even if it did, it still wouldn't generate that output. So I wouldn't put to much value on anything that's said in that question.

Comment: @user3386109 Yepp, agree. That seems reasonable. (Otherwise, I wouldn't know how to explain this...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Hadn't noticed that. Oh well, the OP can get back in touch if there are still problems.

Comment: Better solution: don't use any global variables, _particularly_ not when you are a newbie.